# How to calculate difference between multiple dates in Stata?

Tags: date, stata

I have 10 date variables in Stata for each ID in wide format, I want to check difference between each of the two consecutive dates and the difference between two consecutive dates shouldn't be less than 8 days

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: id            visit1           visit2       visit3             visit4
001         2/3/2014         2/5/2014      2/7/2014  2/10/2014
002    2/3/2014         2/5/2014      2/7/2014  2/10/2014
004          2/19/2014 2/21/2014      2/24/2014  2/26/2014
005         2/28/2014 3/4/2014      3/6/2014  3/10/2014
008         3/14/2014 3/18/2014      3/20/2014  3/25/2014

Comment: Are these strings or unusually formatted `td` variables?

Comment: these are td formatted variables

Comment: For a Stata question dataex is the equivalent of dput. Please use that.

Answer (score 1):

These types of tasks are generally easier with the panel data in long format:

```
clear

/* clean up data */
input str20(id visit1 visit2 visit3 visit4)
001 "2/3/2014" "2/5/2014" "2/7/2014" "2/10/2014"
002 "2/3/2014" "2/5/2014" "2/7/2014" "2/10/2014"
004 "2/19/2014" "2/21/2014" "2/24/2014" "2/26/2014"
005 "2/28/2014" "3/4/2014" "3/6/2014" "3/10/2014"
008 "3/14/2014" "3/18/2014" "3/20/2014" "3/25/2014"
end

foreach var of varlist visit* {
    gen t = date(`var',"MDY")
    format t %td
    drop `var'
    rename t `var'
}

/* reshape to long format */
destring id, gen(non_str_id)
reshape long visit, i(non_str_id) j(t)

xtset non_str_id t
assert D.visit > 8 & !missing(D.visit)

/* reshape back to wide after fixing problematic data */
drop non_str_id
reshape wide visit, i(id) j(t)
```

Comment: @Tom Did this accomplish your goal?